# Cast SYS_REFCURSOR to a PL/SQL Type

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql

I have a stored procedure that calls a function that returns a SYS_REFCURSOR. The function returns a SYS_REFCURSOR because this function is also called from Java application and Java does not understand rowtype.

Here is my function.

```
function f_get_building(
    p_building_id in T_BUILDING.ID%type
  ) return sys_refcursor 
  AS
    v_cursor sys_refcursor;
  BEGIN

    open v_cursor for
        select 
            BUILDING_ID,
            CAMPUS_ID,
            DELETE_FLAG,
            max(EFFECTIVE_DATE),
            END_DATE,
            IMAGE_URL,
            INSTITUTION_ID,
            LOCAL_ID,
            LOCATION_ID,
            NAME
        from V_BUILDING
        where BUILDING_ID = p_building_id
        group by
            BUILDING_ID,
            CAMPUS_ID,
            DELETE_FLAG,
            END_DATE,
            IMAGE_URL,
            INSTITUTION_ID,
            LOCAL_ID,
            LOCATION_ID,
            NAME;

    return v_cursor;

  END f_get_building;
```

In another stored procedure I am also calling this function but having issues using it. Here is the stored procedure.

```
procedure sp_delete_building(
    p_building_id in T_BUILDING.ID%type,
    p_permanent_delete in boolean default false
  ) 
  AS
    v_building_cur sys_refcursor;
    v_building_rec V_BUILDING%rowtype;
  BEGIN

    -- if permanment delete
    if p_permanent_delete = true
    then
        delete from T_BUILDING where ID = p_building_id;
    -- otherwise perform soft delete
    else
        -- lookup
        v_building_cur := f_get_building(p_building_id);

        -- if cursor is empty there is nothing to do
        if v_building_cur%notfound then
            return;
        end if;

        fetch v_building_cur into v_building_rec; -- this line is where the error happens

        -- if its already deleted nothing to do
        if v_building_rec.DELETE_FLAG = 'Y'
        then
            return;
        else
            insert into T_BUILDING_ATTRIBUTE(BUILDING_ID,EFFECTIVE_DATE,DELETE_FLAG,
                IMAGE_URL,LOCATION_ID,NAME)
            values (v_building_rec.BUILDING_ID,current_timestamp,'Y',v_building_rec.IMAGE_URL
                ,v_building_rec.LOCATION_ID,v_building_rec."NAME");
         end if;
    end if;

  END sp_delete_building;
```

I am getting the following PL/SQL stacktrace.

```
ORA-01722: invalid number
ORA-06512: at "OBR.PKG_BUILDING", line 114
ORA-06512: at line 8
```

Forgive my ignorance, this is my first project using PL/SQL, I would classify myself as a Java developer, not a database developer. Since I am selecting everything from V_BUILDING I expected I would just be able to case it as a rowtype inside the stored procedure. How can I use my function inside my stored procedure?

Update:

Here is the create statement for V_BUILDING

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FORCE VIEW "OBR"."V_BUILDING" ("BUILDING_ID", "LOCAL_ID", "INSTITUTION_ID", "EFFECTIVE_DATE", "END_DATE", "DELETE_FLAG", "CAMPUS_ID", "LOCATION_ID", "IMAGE_URL", "NAME") AS 
  SELECT
    ba.BUILDING_ID,
    b.LOCAL_ID,
    b.INSTITUTION_ID,
    ba.EFFECTIVE_DATE,
  NVL(MIN(ba2.EFFECTIVE_DATE - INTERVAL '0.000001' SECOND),TO_DATE('31-DEC-9999', 'DD-MON-YYYY')) AS END_DATE,
    ba.DELETE_FLAG,
    ba.CAMPUS_ID,
    ba.LOCATION_ID,
    ba.IMAGE_URL,
    ba.NAME
FROM
    T_BUILDING b
INNER JOIN T_BUILDING_ATTRIBUTE ba
    ON b.ID = ba.BUILDING_ID
LEFT JOIN T_BUILDING_ATTRIBUTE ba2
  ON ba.BUILDING_ID = ba2.BUILDING_ID
  AND ba2.EFFECTIVE_DATE > ba.EFFECTIVE_DATE
GROUP BY
  ba.BUILDING_ID,
    b.LOCAL_ID,
    b.INSTITUTION_ID,
    ba.EFFECTIVE_DATE,
    ba.DELETE_FLAG,
    ba.CAMPUS_ID,
    ba.LOCATION_ID,
    ba.IMAGE_URL,
    ba.NAME
ORDER BY ba.BUILDING_ID, ba.EFFECTIVE_DATE DESC;
```

Update 2:

Here is a screenshot of the types in the view

[image]

CAMPUS_ID - NUMBER(10)
LOCATION_ID - NUMBER(10)
IMAGE_URL - VARCHAR(500)
NAME - VARCHAR(255)
BUILDING_ID - NUMBER(10)
LOCAL_ID - VARCHAR(30)
INSTITUTION_ID - NUMBER(10)
EFFECTIVE_DATE - TIMESTAMP(6)
END_DATE - TIMESTAMP (6)
DELETE_FLAG - CHAR(1)

Comment: Is the ref cursor returning all the v_building columns in the same order that they appear in the table?

Comment: It would be helpful if you could edit your question to include the create table statement for the v_building table.

Comment: I've added the create ddl for the view

Comment: Ok, could you give us the declaration of the view? Ie. columns and their datatypes

Comment: The order of the columns in your query is different than the order in the view, I would assume that this causes the problem.

Comment: @Boneist I've added the screen shot

Comment: unfortunately, I can't see the image as it's blocked by my work's firewall.

Comment: @PeterLang, okay that makes sense, but that leads to another issue because I need to do a MAX on the effective date so I get back only the most recent building record because the system keeps a running history of updates of buildings, so maybe I can't use rowtype? What else can I use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are the list of columns and their datatypes as returned by the view and the ref cursor:

```
LIST OF COLS FROM VIEW  DATATYPE FROM VIEW  LIST OF COLS FROM CURSOR  DATATYPE FROM CURSOR
----------------------  ------------------  ------------------------  --------------------
BUILDING_ID             NUMBER(10)          BUILDING_ID               NUMBER(10)
LOCAL_ID                VARCHAR(30)         CAMPUS_ID                 NUMBER(10)
INSTITUTION_ID          NUMBER(10)          DELETE_FLAG               CHAR(1)
EFFECTIVE_DATE          TIMESTAMP(6)        max(EFFECTIVE_DATE)       TIMESTAMP(6)
END_DATE                TIMESTAMP(6)        END_DATE                  TIMESTAMP(6)
DELETE_FLAG             CHAR(1)             IMAGE_URL                 VARCHAR(500)
CAMPUS_ID               NUMBER(10)          INSTITUTION_ID            NUMBER(10)
LOCATION_ID             NUMBER(10)          LOCAL_ID                  VARCHAR(30)
IMAGE_URL               VARCHAR(500)        LOCATION_ID               NUMBER(10)
NAME                    VARCHAR(255)        NAME                      VARCHAR(255)
```

They are not the same, yet by using the `V_BUILDING%ROWTYPE` in your sp_delete_building procedure, you're treating the ref cursor results as if the column order is the same as that of the view.

You can see that there are several mismatches between the datatypes of the view and the cursor select lists - it's probably the "LOCATION_ID/LOCAL_ID" mismatch that's causing the invalid number error that you're seeing.

You either need to change the order of your ref cursor so that the list of columns is returned in the same order as that of the view, or to explicitly list the columns of the cursor in the v_building_rec record type.

As an aside, you should give your `max(EFFECTIVE_DATE)` column in the refcursor an alias.

Comment: You are correct, once I changed the order in my select it worked as expected. Thanks much!

Comment: No problem *{:-) Out of curiosity, why are you using a ref cursor? It doesn't look like you're passing this cursor outside of PL/SQL - could you not just declare it as a "normal" cursor, with a parameter, maybe at the package body level? (E.g. `cursor building_cur is select ...`) That way, you could use a type based directly on the cursor rowtype, and you wouldn't have to worry about the column order so much.

Comment: That function is also called from a java web application using MyBatis to call the function and map it to a java domain object, there is probably a better way to do it but it was the easiest way I could think of where I could utilize the function from both my Java application and within the other PL/SQL code

Comment: Ah ok; sounds reasonable in that case *{:-)